# How can i change ssh port number on centos

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I want to chnage my ssh port number on my server as i can see many attackes and failed login attempts onthat port

1. How can i change that
2. If i  do that , what other places , servces i need to chnage or will be affected by it or will stop working. is anything linking on that port

Answer (score 2):

Modify this value in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
Port 22
```

Then restart sshd.

---

That said, changing the port number is merely security by obscurity, which is not much security at all. Instead of doing this, set yourself up with key auth and then disable `PasswordAuthentication` in your `sshd_config`.

Number two depends on the service. Services ask for the port number to connect to and not many processes require SSH.

Comment: Answering number two, it depends on the service. Any services that you add usually ask for the port number if they connect using SSH (not normal).

Comment: @GabrielGraves I believe you meant to comment on the question, not my answer.

Comment: I just wanted to add to your question instead of creating one of my own as he asked two questions and you answered the first one perfectly and there's no reason to create a new answer and answer both.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Feel free to edit my answer to include the other part.

Comment: @EEAA , you didn't mention one important point which could have landed me trouble. you should have told me to open that new port in iptable , othwise i could have locked myself fro my server. i found that fro internet

Comment: @user75380 you didn't mention having a firewall in place, so how was I supposed to divine that? You're the sysadmin here...

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer states, this doesn't really solve anything. Besides the measures suggested there, consider installing [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net), it is part of the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) semi-official repositories.